# Is TikZ picture or LaTeX document the right tool to create an "information card" with multiple features?

Tags: tikz-pgf, layout

I'm designing a "welcome" card with a couple of bullet points of text, a picture, some symbols and frame decorations. It's to be printed on a A5-size paper.

I want pretty good control over typesetting the margin sizes, spaces, positioning etc. Is the best approach for such a project to make a single TikZ picture or a LaTeX document? (If LaTeX is even a reasonable tool for this at all?)

[image]

Comment: If it is just a one off and you want full control, then I might use pure tikz (maybe having larger  pieces of text in minipages inside nodes). Then the decorations might be easier to do.

Comment: Thank you daleif. Except for small changes to the text or picture every second month or so to recompile and print, it's a one-off project.

Answer (score 2):

One nice package that allows you to combine Ti*k*Z with the efficient automatic layout features of LaTeX is `tikzpagenodes`. Using it, you can place stuff inside or outside the text area. And then the `tikzmark` library can be used to refer to objects in the page, such as items, and add the boxes accordingly.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
 \bfseries\sffamily\Huge Welcome to our site!
\end{center}
\begin{itemize}
 \item \tikzmarknode{blah1}{blah} blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
 blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
 blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
 blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
 \item \tikzmarknode{blah2}{blah} blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
 blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
 blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
 \item \tikzmarknode{blah3}{blah} blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
 blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
 blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
 blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
 \item \tikzmarknode{blah4}{blah} blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
 blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
 blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\end{itemize}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \foreach \X in {1,...,4}
 {\node[minimum width=1.2cm,minimum height=1cm,draw,anchor=north west]
 at ([xshift=1mm]current page text area.east|-blah\X.north) {};}
 \draw[dashed]
 ([xshift=-2mm]current page text area.west) to[out=135,in=-135]
 ++ (0,2) to[out=45,in=-45] ++(0,2);
 \node[anchor=south] at (current page text area.south)
 {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wish to change the page parameters (e.g. width or margin), I recommend using the `geometry` package.